# Multiple derivations of the same object

Tags: c#

I don't know what this is called but here goes.

```
public class Person
{
    long ID;
}

public class Banker : Person
{
    string example1;
}

public class Scientist : Person
{
    string example2;
}
```

I'm trying implement our ORM to match our database and I ran into this problem. Hopefully this example is easy enough to understand.

Now the object-relation mapping makes sense for a person being a Banker or a Scientist. The problem I have been having is the Person being a Banker and a Scientist. So what I'm trying to accomplish is being able to create a Banker or Scientist and being able to cast it to either while having the exact same base class object.

I'm not really looking for multiple inheritance.  What I’m looking for is a way to instantiate multiple objects with the same base class object.  For example the Person is a Banker and a Scientist but not a Banker Scientist (a class having attributes of both banker and a scientist).

This was actually a flaw in the database and the model is now being change but its still a curios question.

Comment: Without really knowing enough about your model, of if this is a real example, but for me this might be better as an association, rather than inheritance - i.e. somebody is a person, but has an occupation (or multiple occupations).  This allows for easier maintenance for the point where you need a banker/scientist/prime minister.  Can be done without changing code.

Comment: Also remember the #1 rule of inheritance: only inherit if you are adding behaviour to the child class. Do not inherit just to add data items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# does not support multiple inheritance so we often use composition or interfaces when we need to model situations similar to yours. Because you are dealing with an ORM you probably need the interface approach. Consider this:

```
interface IPerson { }
interface IBanker : IPerson, IRuinedTheEconomy { }    
interface IScientist : IPerson { }
interface IRobot : IAsimov { }

class Person : IPerson { }
class Banker : Person, IBanker { }
class Scientist : Person, IScientist { }
class BankerAndScientist : Person, IBanker, IScientist { }
```

As for the approach that you are taking, you can't cast between sibling classes (that is, two classes that have the same base class). And that's a good thing. Keep in mind that inheritance is used to model "is a" relationships.

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
```

So here a `Dog` is an `Animal` and a `Cat` is an `Animal` but it makes no sense to be able to cast between the two. Yes, you can define user-defined conversions but don't; that would be a huge design smell.

Comment: Yah, I know I could do something like this, the problem being lets say a person can be a any permutation of 18 careers. So I have to create 18! classes?

Comment: I don't think you mean to use the word "permutation" there. Are you saying that you have eighteen careers in your system and a person can have any (possibly multiple) of the eighteen careers? Can a person really be any possible subset of the eighteen careers (2^18 possible subsets including the empty set)? This is clearly not realistic. If it is realistic, then you need `class Career { // }` and `class Person { HashSet<Career> Careers; // }`.

Comment: For this example, no its not really realistic for a person to be any possible subset of 2^18 careers. But what am I to do define what a person can and can't be that doesn't seem like a optimal solution. (Looking back wow sorry about my horrible math, don't know what I was thinking.)

Comment: Yes, there would be other ways to implement this, however they are out of my control. This is a object relational model, meaning I don't have control over the database layout.  The database layout of the this problem makes perfect logical sense though.

Comment: Ah, classic impedance mismatch. Do you have control of the layer between the database and the domain layer? If you have to design your model to accommodate any possible combination of careers (and knowing nothing else about your system) then I think the above (in my first comment) is a viable approach. Then just let the intermediate layer (between the database and your domain) handle translating between the two.

Comment: Well the problem was with the database model, it was using ‘has a’ instead of ‘is a’. So it was a database design flaw. But looking back multiple inheritance, isn’t exactly what I wanted. What I really wanted to do was instantiate two different objects with the same base class object. The difference being no one object has the properties of multi objects, just the same base object.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in most .NET languages (and C# specifically) - you cannot use [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) to create a BankerScientist:

```
public class BankerScientist : Banker, Scientist { ... }  // illegal
```

The best you can do is use composition. Segregate the details that define a scientist and banker into non-persistent classes, and then compose them into your reltional mapping classes.

You may also be able to use interfaces to define an IScientist and IBanker, that can then be implemented by a BankerScientist class.

Comment: I think that MI is possible in the CLR. I'll try to dig up a reference.

Comment: This blog post seems to imply my above statement to be true: http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85562.aspx "However, I should point out that it's possible for compilers to create MI for their types inside the CLR. There are a few rough edges if you go down this path: the result is unverifiable, there is no interop with other languages via the CLS, and in V1 and V1.1 you may run into deadlocks with the OS loader lock."

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is [Multiple Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) which C# doesn't directly support.

You can use multiple interfaces though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using interfaces. Multiple inheritance isn't supported but a class can inherit multiple interfaces.

You could have an IPerson interface which would be implemented in your Person class, then you would have separate interfaces for IBanker and IScientist which would both be derived from IPerson and could be implemented separately or both at the same time.  Any classes you write could still use the Person class as a base, but could implement whatever interfaces you need in each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this as a rule:

- Use derivation if there is a "is a" relationship
- Use interfaces to represent the "behaves like" relationship

Now considering your example, I would go the way of implementing the `Person` in terms of a `IBanker` and `IScientist` and return the one or other interface to code that needs it. A Banker could become some-when later a Scientist (theoretically ;-) ). In your database you probably also don't have two separate tables or do you? I guess it is something like a flag that differentiate both. It is not the essence of a Banker to be a person, a robot could also behave like a banker. Therefore I would not go the way of deriving Banker from Person, similar argumentation for the Scientist.

I hope it helps.